# Утечки памяти в MVP

Tags: android, android-fragment, mvp

Я начал осваивать mvp и есть только одна проблема. 
Допустим при создании фрагмента из него создается presenter в конструктор которого передается ссылка на фрагмент. Теперь я поворачиваю телефон и presenter пересоздается. Получается что ссылка на прошлый инстанс фрагмента висит в памяти. 
Что с этим можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать [DI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) для внедрения презентеров (и не только презентеров). При построении MVP в презентер передается абстракция (интерфейс, который имплементирует Ваша view). Ваш код станет слабосвязанным, не будет жестких ссылок на фрагменты или активити в презентере. Это позволит избежать утечек памяти.
Много информации на разных ресурсах есть на эту тему. К примеру, [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/263465/).